# Reverseproxied Wordpress Docker stack keeps redirecting to old domain name

Tags: migration, ssl, nginx, docker, proxy

I am running a Docker stack with Wordpress and MariaDB on a Linux machine and routing  everything with Nginx-Proxy-Manager.

## First attempt

- I tried to migrate a website I have running on a different tech stack to this configuration, but regular back-up plug-in's refuse to work.

So, I manually copied my website to the new tech stack using a different domain name. Now, I want to migrate it to the domain name, but my browsers are redirected to the old domain name.

## Further attempts

- I tried clearing my browsers DNS cache.
- I tried replacing all substrings "old.domain" in my database with "new.domain" dumping the database, modifying it and uploading it.
- I tried replacing all substrings "old.domain" in my database with "new.domain" with a plug-in like Better Search Replace that should take serialization into account, whatever that is.

## Along the way

- I made sure I restart the containers every time I am done trying something new.
- I made sure my proxying is correct and tried using the old SSL certificate and asking for a new one every time I tried something new.
- I made sure my config.php file is not redirecting to the old domain name.
- I made sure the folder permissions for my volumes are correct.

To me, it is a miracle, that I can still access the new site with the temporary domain. And I just don't know what else to try.